# Search in Full name column with first and last name

Tags: mysql

I want to achieve is to search for a full name in a database with only a string with his first and last name.

in database there is the full name:

```
Manuel Augusto Vieira Conde Fialho
```

and I want a sql query that can search this full name only with the first and last name :

```
Manuel Fialho
```

I've tried this one:

```
SELECT name FROM partners WHERE name LIKE 'Manuel Fialho'";
```

but this does not work for me because I don't have any `Manuel Fialho` in the database only a `Manuel Augusto Vieira Conde Fialho` and because of that the name im looking for does not show.

thank you

Comment: can you please try my query? It working fine for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Below Query:

It works fine..!

```
SELECT * FROM `partners` WHERE 
`name` LIKE replace( 'Manuel Fialho', ' ', '%' ) OR
`name` LIKE replace('%Manuel Fialho%', ' ', '%' ) OR
`name` LIKE replace('%Manuel Fialho', ' ', '' ) OR
`name` LIKE replace('%Manuel Fialho%', ' ', '' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoould add %:

```
SELECT name FROM partners WHERE name LIKE 'Manuel%Fialho';
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses wildcards:

```
SELECT name
FROM partners
WHERE name LIKE REPLACE('Manuel Fialho', ' ', '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM partners WHERE name LIKE "Manuel%" OR name LIKE "%Fialho";
```

If You are sure about the last name of the name then you can also use `AND`

```
 SELECT name FROM partners WHERE name LIKE "Manuel%" AND name LIKE "%Fialho";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible options to search.

Split search string into multiple words and query with that many `LIKE` patterns.

```
select name FROM partners WHERE name LIKE '%Manuel%' or name like '%Fialho%'
```

If you are sure that the sequence of words in the search strings are to match with those in the column value then `replace` all spaces with `%` symbol and use with `LIKE`.

```
select name FROM partners
 WHERE name LIKE concat( '%', replace( 'Manuel Fialho', ' ', '%' ), '%' )
```